# WARNING : <DATA DIRECTORY> option ignored

Tags: mysql

I use attribute DATA DIRECTORY

My code:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t2(id int) ENGINE=MyiSam DATA DIRECTORY='D:/';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.05 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                         |
+---------+------+---------------------------------+
| Warning | 1618 | <DATA DIRECTORY> option ignored |
+---------+------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How fixed warning ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html has a ton of restrictions listed. Google has loads of results. Why do you not search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> These options work only when you are not using the --skip-symbolic-links option. Your operating system must also have a working, thread-safe realpath() call.

Form a post on [the MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,391628,391631#msg-391631)

> My understanding is that the Windows implementation of realpath() is incomplete, so create table data dir and index dir options don't work on Windows.

Therefore, you might be able to get a different folder using relative paths, or possibly [using symbolic links](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html)